# Book: twisted network programming essentials, Example 9-1 does not work

Tags: python, authentication, twisted, telnet, credentials

I am going the book twisted network programming essentials 2nd edition by Jessica McKellar and Abe Fetting. I am stuck on the following twisted cred auth example 9-1. I have double checked my code line by line, letter by letter. The code will run and when I connect with a telnet client and enter 'user pass' it will not log me in. I just get the not authorized message. The script it self does not generate any error message or exceptions.

Thanks

```
import sys
from zope.interface import implements, Interface

from twisted.cred import checkers, credentials, portal
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.python.log import startLogging; startLogging(sys.stdout)

class IPortocolAvatar(Interface):
    def logout():
        """
        Clean up per-login resource allocated to this avatar.
        """

class EchoAvatar(object):
    implements(IPortocolAvatar)

    def logout(self):
        pass

class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    portal = None
    avatar = None
    logout = None

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.logout:
            self.logout()
            self.avatar = None
            self.logout = None

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if not self.avatar:
            # print "line [32]: %s" % (line,)
            username, password = line.strip().split(" ")
            self.tryLogin(username, password)

        else:
            self.sendLine(line)

    def tryLogin(self, username, password):
        self.portal.login(credentials.UsernamePassword(username, password), None, PortocolAvatar).addCallbacks(self._cbLogin, self._ebLogin)

    def _cbLogin(self, (interface, avatar, logout)):
        self.avatar = avatar
        self.logout = logout
        self.sendLine("Login sucessful, please proceed.")

    def _ebLogin(self, failure):
        self.sendLine("Login denied, goodbye.")
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self, portal):
        self.portal = portal

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        proto = Echo()
        proto.portal = self.portal
        return proto

class Realm(object):
    implements(portal.IRealm)

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if IPortocolAvatar in interfaces:
            avatar = EchoAvatar()
            return IPortocolAvatar, avatar, avatar.logout

        raise NotImplementedError(
            "This realm only supports the IPortocolAvatar interface.")

realm = Realm()
myPortal = portal.Portal(realm)
checker = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
checker.addUser("user", "pass")
myPortal.registerChecker(checker)

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory(myPortal))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: If you enable logging, you'll get to see errors like the one this example produces: `from twisted.python.log import startLogging; startLogging(sys.stdout)`

Comment: Thanks, that is cool. I will add that to my other scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `tryLogin` (`ProtocolAvatar` -> `IProtocolAvatar`):

```
def tryLogin(self, username, password):
    self.portal.login(credentials.UsernamePassword(username, password), None, IProtocolAvatar).addCallbacks(self._cbLogin, self._ebLogin)
    #                                                                         ^
```

**UPDATE**

There is another typo: `IPortocolAvatar` -> `IProtocolAvatar`.

After run the server, try following test client code:

```
import telnetlib
import time

t = telnetlib.Telnet('localhost', 8000)
t.write(b'user pass\r\n')
t.write(b'blah blah\r\n')
time.sleep(1)
print(t.read_eager())
```

Comment: I am not sure what happened. My original code has the missing 'I'. I am still not getting an error or the correct result. script terminal:erik@couriosity:/srv/twisted/ch9$ python echo_cred.py
2013-10-04 09:30:32-0700 [-] Log opened.
2013-10-04 09:30:32-0700 [-] EchoFactory starting on 8000
2013-10-04 09:30:32-0700 [-] Starting factory <__main__.EchoFactory instance at 0x1cce3f8>
FROM TELNET: Login denied, goodbye.


Connection to host lost.

Press any key to continue...

Comment: @Eman, I found another typo. See the UPDATE. I also added test client code.

Comment: That was it. There were 3 times where I miss typed IPortocolAvatar. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm also made the example run with python3. 
Here is my altered code for the 'Example 9-1. echo_cred.py' from the book 'Twisted Network Programming Essentials, 2nd Edition'

```
from zope.interface import Interface, implementer
from twisted.cred import checkers, credentials, portal, error
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, defer

from twisted.protocols import basic

class IProtocolAvatar(Interface):
    def logout():
        """
        Clean up per-login resources allocated to this avatar.
        """

@implementer(IProtocolAvatar)    
class EchoAvatar():

    def logout(self):
        pass

class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    portal = None
    avatar = None
    logout = None

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.logout:
            self.logout()
            self.avatar = None
            self.logout = None

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print('line received')
        if not self.avatar:
            username, password = line.strip().split()
            # convert 2 text code
            username, password = username.decode(), password.decode()

            d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.tryLogin, username, password)
            d.addCallbacks(self._cbLogin, self._ebLogin)
        else:
            self.sendLine(line)

    def tryLogin(self, username, password):
        if self.portal is not None:
            return self.portal.login(
                credentials.UsernamePassword(username, password),
                None,
                IProtocolAvatar
            )
        raise error.UnauthorizedLogin()        

    def _cbLogin(self, ial):
        interface, avatar, logout = ial
        self.avatar = avatar
        self.logout = logout
        # convert 2 byte code
        self.sendLine("Login successful, please proceed.".encode())

    def _ebLogin(self, failure):
        self.sendLine("Login denied, goodbye.".encode())
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self, portal):
        self.portal = portal

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        proto = Echo()
        proto.portal = self.portal
        return proto

@implementer(portal.IRealm)    
class Realm():

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if IProtocolAvatar in interfaces:
            avatar = EchoAvatar()
            return IProtocolAvatar, avatar, avatar.logout
        raise NotImplementedError("This realm only supports the IProtocolAvatar interface.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    realm = Realm()
    myPortal = portal.Portal(realm)
    checker = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
    checker.addUser("user", "pass")
    myPortal.registerChecker(checker)
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory(myPortal))
    reactor.run()
```